# Python not able to correctly append a list to a list

Tags: python

I have a file named divider.csv with below contents
[divider.csv contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2wpO.png)
The below program copies the contents of this file into variable 'total'

```
import csv

total = list()
temp_list_helper = list()

with open('divider.csv') as file_obj:
   reader_obj = csv.reader(file_obj)
   for row in reader_obj:
      for a in row:
         temp_list_helper.append(int(a))
      total.append(temp_list_helper)
      print(total)
      temp_list_helper.clear()
```

The output is as follows

```
[[-16963, -135, -165, -855, 484, 442, -107, -815, 1302, -1349, -1530, 1016, -351, 98, -188, 1234, 780, -812, -679, 4326, -7363, -2842, -3012, 1583, -3817, -4370, -3722, 4775, 3254, 2372, -8930, 1212, 2204, -5689, 1849, 1590, -4452, 3462, -8435, 4024, -189, 5059, 2255, 873, -1529, -3092, 906, 5791, 1904, 2190, -7520]]
[[29845, -28, 465, -195, -1123, 1669, 1755, 857, -3489, -3400, -542, -1009, 571, -1179, 3976, -3333, -2647, 5000, 3339, 6181, 1886, -6547, -2860, -2778, 3960, 2177, -4167, -3380, -1829, 3590, -1535, 5089, 1242, -338, 1826, -5699, -224, 194, 3144, 5578, 224, 3635, -4730, -5305, -1057, 2664, 1373, 925, 1166, 2916, 21837], [29845, -28, 465, -195, -1123, 1669, 1755, 857, -3489, -3400, -542, -1009, 571, -1179, 3976, -3333, -2647, 5000, 3339, 6181, 1886, -6547, -2860, -2778, 3960, 2177, -4167, -3380, -1829, 3590, -1535, 5089, 1242, -338, 1826, -5699, -224, 194, 3144, 5578, 224, 3635, -4730, -5305, -1057, 2664, 1373, 925, 1166, 2916, 21837]]
[[3231, -273, -81, 211, 227, 1091, 906, -1023, 279, -111, 1072, 570, 1261, 759, -1927, 2958, 138, 905, 2467, 141, -1711, -5792, -1007, -2484, 326, -6297, -5845, 94, -1109, -3426, 2907, -1987, -830, 2798, -549, 7207, -339, -548, -2081, -1711, 789, -996, -2054, 6114, 2429, -6915, 7946, 4191, 1434, 6793, -3686], [3231, -273, -81, 211, 227, 1091, 906, -1023, 279, -111, 1072, 570, 1261, 759, -1927, 2958, 138, 905, 2467, 141, -1711, -5792, -1007, -2484, 326, -6297, -5845, 94, -1109, -3426, 2907, -1987, -830, 2798, -549, 7207, -339, -548, -2081, -1711, 789, -996, -2054, 6114, 2429, -6915, 7946, 4191, 1434, 6793, -3686], [3231, -273, -81, 211, 227, 1091, 906, -1023, 279, -111, 1072, 570, 1261, 759, -1927, 2958, 138, 905, 2467, 141, -1711, -5792, -1007, -2484, 326, -6297, -5845, 94, -1109, -3426, 2907, -1987, -830, 2798, -549, 7207, -339, -548, -2081, -1711, 789, -996, -2054, 6114, 2429, -6915, 7946, 4191, 1434, 6793, -3686]]
```

As we see above, the initial values are not being stored and its getting overwritten by new values. What is the mistake done here and the solution?

Answer (score 3):

You are still using the same instance of a list in `temp_list_helper` for every row. You need to create a new list each time round:

```
import csv

total = []

with open('divider.csv') as file_obj:
   reader_obj = csv.reader(file_obj)
   for row in reader_obj:
      temp_list_helper = []
      for a in row:
         temp_list_helper.append(int(a))
      total.append(temp_list_helper)
      print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you append `temp_list_helper` you are appending a **reference** to that specific list.

If you clear `temp_list_helper` you are clearing also the reference (which means the inserted one inside `total`)

Yo should instantiate `temp_list_helper` on every iteration of the loop

Just modify `temp_list_helper.clear()` by `temp_list_helper = []`, or add it at the beginning of the loop:

```
for row in reader_obj:
    temp_list_helper = []  # clear the list
    for a in row:
       ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem will be solved by setting the temp_list_helper list to an empty list at the start of every repetition. That can be achieved with the following code:

```
import csv

total = list()

with open('divider.csv') as file_obj:
   reader_obj = csv.reader(file_obj)
   for row in reader_obj:
      temp_list_helper = []
      for a in row:
         temp_list_helper.append(int(a))
      total.append(temp_list_helper)
      print(total)
```